# Custom SWIG Wrapping to Handle Nested C Structures

Tags: swig

I have the below C struct that has a couple nested structures that have proven to be difficult to deal with using my knowledge of SWIG. Everything below is easily wrapped by SWIG execept for *saddr* (C socket address) and *mac[6]* (C array representing a MAC address).  Since SWIG gives me the pointer value (SWIGTYPE_p_unsigned_char and SWIGTYPE_p_sockaddr), I would like to somehow call a helper C function to convert the pointer to a char*.  I have the helper function, but I don't know the best way to plug this into SWIG.  Is there any way to configure the getMac() and getSaddr() to call the helper function?

**C Structure Trying To Wrap:**

```
%rename (Details) details_t_;
    typedef struct details_t_ {
        uint16_t                      code;
        char                          *name;              
        **sockaddr                      *saddr;**             
        uint32_t                      saddr_len;
        uint8_t                       flag;       
        ios_boolean                   is_child;             
        **unsigned char                 mac[6];**            
    } details_t;
```

**Generated Java Code:**

```
  public void setMac(SWIGTYPE_p_unsigned_char value) {
    TestJNI.Details_mac_set(swigCPtr, this, SWIGTYPE_p_unsigned_char.getCPtr(value));
  }

  public SWIGTYPE_p_unsigned_char getMac() {
    long cPtr = TestJNI.Details_mac_get(swigCPtr, this);
    return (cPtr == 0) ? null : new SWIGTYPE_p_unsigned_char(cPtr, false);
  }

public void setSaddr(SWIGTYPE_p_sockaddr value) {
    TestJNI.Details_saddr_set(swigCPtr, this, SWIGTYPE_p_sockaddr.getCPtr(value));
  }

  public SWIGTYPE_p_sockaddr getSaddr() {
    long cPtr = TestJNI.Details_saddr_get(swigCPtr, this);
    return (cPtr == 0) ? null : new SWIGTYPE_p_sockaddr(cPtr, false);
  }
```

**Proposed SWIG.i Changes:**

```
 %module Test
          %rename (realId) details_t_::mac;
            %typemap(javacode) struct details_t_ %{
              public String getMac() {
                return Test.getMacAddressAsString(this); 
               //this is a pointer to details_t_ struct
              }

            %};
                %rename (Details) details_t_;
                    typedef struct details_t_ {
                        uint16_t                      code;
                        char                          *name;              
                        **sockaddr                      *saddr;**             
                        uint32_t                      saddr_len;
                        uint8_t                       flag;       
                        ios_boolean                   is_child;             
                        **unsigned char                 mac[6];**            
                    } details_t;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a `javacode` typemap, e.g.:

```
%module test

%rename (realId) Sample::id;
%typemap(javacode) struct Sample %{
  public byte getId() {
    return 100-getRealId(); // Transform the real call
  }

  public void setId(byte value) {
    setRealId(value+100);
  }
%};


struct Sample {
  char id;
};
```

Renames the generated `getId()` and `setId()`, but provides a Java get/set which can be written in terms of the SWIG generated (but renamed) one. You might want to make the SWIG generated ones private though.

Comment: thanks for the example.  I applied it to my SWIG.i (see above) and everything seems to work fine. I am doing something a bit different that you.  I'm calling another c function from the new getter (getId()) and it requires a pointer to the struct (Sample) to return the correct value.  I'm just passing "this" and it works, but is there any memory impacts with doing it this way?

Comment: If I wanted to apply multiple javacode typemaps for the same struct, is it possible?  I've tried to duplicate the %rename and %typemap code and apply it for a different struct attribute, but it only creates the last one specified in the module.

Comment: @c12 I think you can only have one javacode typemap per type. What you described sounds fine though